# Mailchimp.Net api code is giving exception when adding interest group

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailchimp

I am using [Mailchimp.Net](https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET) in an asp.net C# web application.

I am trying to add a interest group using following code:

```
MailChimp.MailChimpManager mailChimpManager = new MailChimp.MailChimpManager("xxxxxxxxxxxx-us9");
if (Session["listId"] != null)
    {
                        string listId = Session["listId"].ToString();

                        List<InterestGrouping.InnerGroup> innerGroup = new List<InterestGrouping.InnerGroup>();
                        innerGroup.Add(new InterestGrouping.InnerGroup() { Name = "Students", Bit = 1, DisplayOrder = 1, Subscribers = 0 });

                        mailChimpManager.AddListInterestGrouping(listId, this.textBoxNewGroup.Text, "radio", innerGroup);

    }
```

but `AddListInterestGrouping` method is giving following exception:

```
MailChimp.Errors.MailChimpAPIException: A backend database error has occurred. Please try again later or report this issue.
```

Internal excpetion is:

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I am not getting why is this issue occurring, as other methods of the api are working.  Has anyone faced this before or do I report it to the author ? 
Please help.